# Tslint: JSX elements with no children must be self closing [Error]

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tslint

So I've been searching for a solution to this issue. My solution will not build via the command `npm run build` as I have the error:

> JSX elements with no children must be self-closing.

There is a similar issue here with no accepted (or working) answers: [JSX elements with no children must be self-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652887/jsx-elements-with-no-children-must-be-self-closing)

The associated `Typescript`/`HTML` is of the format:

```
class ExampleClass { 
    render() {
           return <div>
               <div> 
                   <div>Content 1</div>
                   <div>Content 2</div>
                   <div>Content 3</div>
              </div>
          </div>;
      }
}
export default ExampleClass;
```

The "error" occurs on line 5 which is:

```
<div>Content 1</div>
```

I'm using [Tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) and have a number of the features of Tslint already changed / working in the file `tslint.json`.

See the `tslint.json` file as it currently stands:

```
{
  "extends": ["tslint:recommended", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier"],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "gulpfile.js",
      "bin/**",
      "wwwroot/**",
      "config/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "prefer-const": false,
    "triple-equals": false,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "object-literal-shorthand": false,
    "no-shadowed-variable": false,
    "ban-types": false,
    "one-variable-per-declaration": false,
    "callable-types": false,
    "quotemark": [ false, "single", "jsx-double" ],
    "indent": [ true, "spaces", 2 ],
    "interface-name": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
    "comment-format": false,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": false,
    "one-line": false,
    "max-classes-per-file": false,
    "jsx-boolean-value": false,
    "no-empty-interface": false,
    "variable-name": [ true, "allow-pascal-case", "allow-snake-case" ],
    "no-console": false,
    "interface-over-type-literal": false
  }
}
```

Here are the various things I've tried (consecutively, not all at once) - with no success:

```
"prefer-const": [
      true,
      { "destructuring": "all" }
    ],
"react/self-closing-comp": "off",
"react/self-closing-comp": false,
"no-trailing-whitespace":  false
```

The rules for Tslint can be found here: [TSLint core rules](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/)

What I'm **not** looking to do is:

- Completely disable TSLint
- Modify my HTML structure unless totally necessary

**What I'm looking for is the correct Tslint rule to use to suppress this error.**

 E.g. `"react/self-closing-comp": false`.

Hopefully someone out there has seen this before & can give me a hand!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-react) as of the 20/01/2020:

> TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint-react/issues/210 for more information.

You can configure your existing TSLint solution to use the new rules from ESLint, this is done like so:

1. According to [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react), install ESLint with the npm command: `npm install eslint --save-dev`
2. According to [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-eslint-rules), allow the ESLint rules by running the following command: `npm install --save-dev tslint-eslint-rules`
3. Modify your `tslint.json` file by adding an `extends` property, like so: `"extends": [ "tslint-eslint-rules"]`

A good number of relevant ESLint rules are found here: [ESLint Rules - npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-eslint-rules) and here [ESLint Rules - eslint.org](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/)

The relevant rule to fix the error:

> JSX elements with no children must be self-closing.

was this:

```
 "jsx-self-close": false
```

My final `tslint.json` file looked like this:

```
{
  "extends": [ "tslint-eslint-rules", "tslint:latest", "tslint-react", "tslint-config-prettier" ],
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "gulpfile.js",
      "bin/**",
      "wwwroot/**",
      "config/**/*.js",
      "node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "rules": {
    "jsx-self-close": false,
    "jsx-wrap-multiline": false,
    "no-constant-condition": true,
    "no-unused-expression": false,
    "no-unused-variable": false,
    "no-string-throw": false,
    "prefer-const": false,
    "triple-equals": false,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "object-literal-shorthand": false,
    "no-shadowed-variable": false,
    "ban-types": false,
    "one-variable-per-declaration": false,
    "callable-types": false,
    "quotemark": [ false, "single", "jsx-double" ],
    "indent": [ true, "spaces", 2 ],
    "interface-name": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
    "comment-format": false,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": false,
    "one-line": false,
    "max-classes-per-file": false,
    "jsx-boolean-value": false,
    "no-empty-interface": false,
    "variable-name": false,
    "no-console": false,
    "interface-over-type-literal": false,
    "no-conditional-assignment": false,
    "only-arrow-functions": false,
    "no-var-keyword": false,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-submodule-imports": false,
    "no-duplicate-imports": false,
    "no-useless-rename": false,
    "no-implicit-dependencies": false,
    "no-return-await": false,
    "no-object-literal-type-assertion": false,
    "prefer-object-spread": false,
    "prefer-conditional-expression": false,
    "jsdoc-format": false,
    "prefer-for-of": false,
    "radix": false
  }
}
```

Hopefully this saves someone some time!